# convert xaml to c#

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

Could you please help me convert something like this:

```
<TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Text = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TextBox.Text}" />
```

to c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be following

```
TextBox MyTextBox = new TextBox();
MyTextBox.Name = "MyTextBox";
Binding binding = new Binding("TextBox.Text");
binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.TemplatedParent);
MyTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: help the user convert, or understand the conversion process. Don't just do it for him.